# FAPI text_format field value not being passed to submit handler

Tags: 8, forms

I created a form that I wanted to be reusable. So I created to form below to imported into a add form and a edit form. Please be aware I do have the validateForm, and submitForm function in my code.

```
class PaneConfigurationForm extends ConfigFormBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'admin_pane_settings';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $element = null) {

       $form['description'] = array(
          '#type' => 'text_format',
          '#title' => 'description',
          '#default_value' => '<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>',
          '#value' => '<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>',
          '#format' => 'full_html',
       );

       return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    }
}
```

So in my AddPane form I use the \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm() function to get the form and apply it to my parent form. For some reason when I submit the form the value is not passed to the submit handler, only to form format.

```
class AddPaneForm extends Formbase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'add_admin_pane';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $element = null) {


          $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\_module_\Form\PaneConfigurationForm');

          $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
          );
    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
          $form_state->getValue('description')
    }
}
```

What can I do to allow the format and value to be passed to the submit handler, not just the text_format field's format.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `#value`:

```
$form['description'] = array(
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => 'description',
  '#default_value' => '<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>',
  '#format' => 'full_html',
);
```

`#value` permeates all the way through a form build/validation/submission, and doesn't get replaced with user input.

`#default_value` will cover the initial value when the form loads.

Comment: If I remove value, I get an error on the AddPaneForm page that says it is needed. Also when I save the AddPaneForm page $form_state->getValue('description') still doesn't get the value. Only the format.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing that - you should only use `#value` if you want to override user input. It's not a required property, that must be something configured specifically on your site somehow. Search the /core folder for `'#type' => 'text_format'` and you'll find dozens of examples of the same thing in core that don't have the `#value` property (and work fine)

Comment: I know. I think the problem may stem from the fact that I'm an using the `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()` get form function to pull in another form. I'm sure is I used a pure `'#type' => 'text_format'` instead of one being rendered via the `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()` everything would work as intended. I just can't figure out why `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()` causes such an issue.

Comment: were you able to see that?